# Can someone tell me what's wrong with my jQuery live method?

Tags: jquery, live, livequery

I've created this simple time picker app but for some reason this snippet of code isn't working.  I had it working (maybe it was my imagination).

I have 4 radio buttons.  With each button having a click event attached (using jquery's live method), I show a DIV and hide the other DIVs.  I also (i thought i was) adding a plugin's method to the newly shown DIV.

Take a look at the link below and you'll see what I mean.  The first DIV works, but subsequent ones don't.  What am I missing?

Thanks!

http://jsbin.com/ebige3

Comment: Please add your code to the post to make it easier for us to examine.

Comment: Live method is doing it's job, it does hide and show the divs, look at the html using firebug and it will highlight the changes in the source.

Comment: @Nathan: the code is in the link in the message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of problems with your code. For one thing, there are several textboxes with the id's `starttime` and `endtime`, whereas an id should occur only once in the document.

What's causing your problem is the fact that upon the click of *any* radiobutton, the `timepicker` will be initialized for *all* elements matching the `$("#starttime, #endtime")` selector. That will mean the first `div` (which is visible), works OK, and the select fields get positioned alright, but for subsequent `div`'s, it is being positioned at a time when the div they're associated with are hidden, and as such, their positions cannot be calculated.

I'd consider changing the code so that your `div`'s have id's called "recur1", "recur2", etc, rather than "daily" and "weekly", and also give al of them a class, "recur". Then you'll be able to remove all your if-statements and just do:

```
$('.recur').hide();
$('#recur'+recurType).show();
```

It'll also enable you to do this, which will solve your problem:

```
$('#recur'+recurType).find("#starttime, #endtime").timePicker({ ... });
```

Comment: as i said, you also want to make `starttime` and `endtime` *classes*, not *ids*. once you've done that, simply edit the last selector to `$('#recur'+recurType).find('.starttime, .endtime')`

Comment: @David:  yes! that worked AWESOMELY!  Shrunk my code by alot too.
You sir deserve more than one checkmark.  Thank you for helping me understand being a more efficient coder.